# SQLException database is locked

Tags: android, sql

I have an application which should write some information to my DB lets say onDestroy (playlist in audio player, for example), so I start new AsyncTask to execute this feauture - open connection, exec many (to 1000 or more) inserts and close connection.
And I need to restore this 1000 or more items from DB onCreate.

Can you give me a hint how to ensure that this operations will not be performed simultaneously to avoid "database is locked" exceptions? Or am I doing something wrong maybe.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the documentation for SQLiteDatabase (and SQLite). You can do transactions in EXCLUSIVE mode.
2. Alternatively, use a ContentProvider, use applyBatch, ContentProviderOperation, and "yield" to prevent lockups.